# Internal Server Error 500 while accessing $GITLAB/admin/runners

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I have restored Gitlab from a backup, now every time I try to access the `runners` webpage, I get a Internal Server error.

I have tried uninstalling all configured gitlab-runners and accessing it, the problem persists. Here is a trace from the gitlab-rails/production.log:

```
Started GET "/admin/runners" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-16 07:17:12 -0500
Processing by Admin::RunnersController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 66ms (ActiveRecord: 5.7ms)

ActionView::Template::Error ():
    37: 
    38:     .col-sm-6
    39:       .bs-callout
    40:         = render partial: 'ci/runner/how_to_setup_runner',
    41:                  locals: { registration_token: Gitlab::CurrentSettings.runners_registration_token,
    42:                            type: 'shared',
    43:                            reset_token_url: reset_registration_token_admin_application_settings_path }

lib/gitlab/crypto_helper.rb:27:in `aes256_gcm_decrypt'
app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable_strategies/encrypted.rb:55:in `get_token'
app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable_strategies/base.rb:33:in `ensure_token!'
app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable.rb:43:in `block in add_authentication_token_field'
app/models/application_setting.rb:409:in `runners_registration_token'
lib/gitlab/current_settings.rb:19:in `method_missing'
app/views/admin/runners/index.html.haml:40:in `_app_views_admin_runners_index_html_haml___977288809002382166_69944849285200'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:116:in `render'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:55:in `with_locale'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:61:in `with_user_locale'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:420:in `set_locale'
lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:103:in `call'
lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:16:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:19:in `call'
lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/correlation_id.rb:16:in `block in call'
lib/gitlab/correlation_id.rb:15:in `use_id'
lib/gitlab/middleware/correlation_id.rb:15:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:40:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in `call'
lib/gitlab/request_context.rb:20:in `call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:13:in `call'
Started GET "/-/metrics" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-16 07:17:24 -0500
Processing by MetricsController#index as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: There isn't enough information there. It looks like an issue with Gitlab::CurrentSettings.runners_registration_token.. put a binding.pry point in at line 40, call Gitlab::CurrentSettings.runners_registration_token and see what error it returns.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You did a restore, but probably did not restore the secrets store (/etc/gitlab/gitlab-secrets.json or $GITLAB_HOME/config/secrets.json). Same issue as [gitlab 500 errors in the admin area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54128023/gitlab-500-errors-in-the-admin-area/54136240#54136240_)

You can reset it like this from the rails console on the gitlab server:

```
root@gitlab:/# gitlab-rails console
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GitLab:       11.5.1 (c90ae59)
 GitLab Shell: 8.4.1
 postgresql:   9.6.8
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Both Deployment and its :status machine have defined a different default for "status". Use only one or the other for defining defaults to avoid unexpected behaviors.
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.10)
irb(main):001:0> ApplicationSetting.current.reset_runners_registration_token!
=> true
```

Comment: Yes, I did not restore the config. Is there a way I can reset it? I have lost the secrets.json.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show a way to reset the token

Comment: This should ideally be added to the documentation.

Comment: make sure you type exit after.  I just ran into this issue and initially still got 500 errors until I typed "exit" to get back out of the gitlab-rails console.

Comment: Did all that but:
```
ERROR: Checking for jobs... forbidden
```

Answer (score 26):

I could resolve the issue by following official gitlab documentation:

```
gitlab-rails dbconsole

-- Clear project tokens
UPDATE projects SET runners_token = null, runners_token_encrypted = null;

-- Clear group tokens
UPDATE namespaces SET runners_token = null, runners_token_encrypted = null;

-- Clear instance tokens
UPDATE application_settings SET runners_registration_token_encrypted = null;

-- Clear runner tokens
UPDATE ci_runners SET token = null, token_encrypted = null;
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html#reset-runner-registration-tokens

**Edit:**

After clearing existing pipeline jobs (see above), I could still not open the ci settings page for some migrated projects where I had set environment variables. In this case try to remove them:

```
gitlab-rails dbconsole
SELECT * FROM ci_variables;
DELETE FROM ci_variables WHERE project_id='XX';
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you!

For anyone on a docker install, use `docker exec -it gitlab_gitlab_1 bin/rails dbconsole` or more comfy : `docker exec -it gitlab_gitlab_1 bash` then from the gitlab directory `/home/git/gitlab` : `bin/rails dbconsole`  (and postgres password can be found in `/home/git/gitlab/config/database.yml`)

Answer (score 3):

i've solved this,maybe it is usefal

```
    a. Reset CI/CD variables
    gitlab-rails dbconsole
    SELECT * FROM public."ci_group_variables";
    SELECT * FROM public."ci_variables";
    DELETE FROM ci_group_variables;
    DELETE FROM ci_variables;
    
    b. Reset runner registration tokens
    gitlab-rails dbconsole
    -- Clear project tokens
    UPDATE projects SET runners_token = null, runners_token_encrypted = null;
    -- Clear group tokens
    UPDATE namespaces SET runners_token = null, runners_token_encrypted = null;
    -- Clear instance tokens
    UPDATE application_settings SET runners_registration_token_encrypted = null;
    UPDATE application_settings SET encrypted_ci_jwt_signing_key = null;
    -- Clear runner tokens
    UPDATE ci_runners SET token = null, token_encrypted = null;
    
    c. Reset pending pipeline jobs
    sudo gitlab-rails dbconsole
    -- Clear build tokens
    UPDATE ci_builds SET token = null, token_encrypted = null;
    
    d. Fix project integrations
    gitlab-rails dbconsole
    -- truncate web_hooks table
    TRUNCATE web_hooks CASCADE;
```

from [gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html#storing-configuration-files)